# How convert resource into string (Nette)

Tags: php

I have image in PostgreSQL. I saved it as `bytea` (escaped by `pg_escape_bytea`). But I cannot get `unescaped` data for sending to browser:

> pg_unescape_bytea() expects parameter 1 to be string, resource given

```
$image = $this->imgRepos->getRecord($id);
$rawimage = pg_unescape_bytea($image->picture);
```

Comment: Highlighted error and highlighted code

Answer (score 0):

```
$rawimage = pg_unescape_bytea(base64_encode($image->picture));
```

There is solution without base 64 encoding which allows You to read image as is, but it needs to read a file - I'm not sure it will take binary image:

```
$rawimage = pg_unescape_bytea(file_get_contents($image->picture));
```